# PyTorch save prediction as CSV for each epoch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I'm trying save the predictions I am getting from a model in PyTorch as csv. The following code. However, the code seem to overwrite the prediction at each epoch and the final .csv file only contains 3 values. Any idea what I am doing wrong please:

```
output = model(images)
preds = output.sum(dim=[1,2,3])
np.savetxt('preds.csv', preds.detach())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your output will be float, you can map that to str and apply join as a comma separated string, finally append row to csv.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch

output = torch.rand(5,5,5,5)
preds = output.sum(dim=[1,2,3])

print(preds)

with open('preds.csv','a') as fd:
    fd.write( ','.join(map(str, preds.detach().tolist())) + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks! This prints the values all in one column. Can i print each epoch into separate columns? Thanks

Comment: @user5576922 updated with slightly more general solution.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. The only thing I ma not sure about is how to add heading to each row, and if possible to format the output as it's outputting into columns instead of rows for each step? Many Thanks for your help

Comment: by the header to each row, do you mean index? you can add an index column by prepending a numeric counter before writing to the CSV. The current solution adds the comma-separated values as a row, are your preds multi-dimensional?

Comment: Thanks !The code iterate through steps of defined batch size Yes, It's a Mutli-dimensional. I would the format of the csv file to be step 1 as header of the first column and so on. Thanks for your help.